# Extracting bbcode quote using java and Android but not extracting the content within the quote tag

Tags: java, regex, string, bbcode

I am going to extract the bbcode with the quotes but to no avail when the actual output is coming.

I would like to implement the bbcode parsing module for extracting the quotes as desired output . The number of quotes shall be a recursive method or some else..

```
INput : 

Testing [quote]http://www.yourube.com?watch?v=asasdsadsa [url] aisa [/url] [/quote] Testing 

   Desired Output
```

Testing 
    http://www.yourube.com?watch?v=asasdsadsa [url] aisa [/url]
     aisa 
Testing

```
Actual Output:

http://www.yourube.com?watch?v=asasdsadsa [url] aisa [/url]
http://www.yourube.com?watch?v=asasdsadsa  aisa
```

The below is my code

```
        String s = "[quote]http://www.yourube.com?watch?v=asasdsadsa [url] aisa [/url][/quote]";
        String t = bbcode(s);
        System.out.println(t);
        String u = bbcode2(t);
        System.out.println(u);

 public static String bbcode(String text) {
        String html = text;

        HashMap<String,String> bbMap = new HashMap<String , String>();


        bbMap.put("\\[quote\\](.+?)\\[/quote\\]", "$1");


        for (Map.Entry entry: bbMap.entrySet()) {
            html = html.replaceAll(entry.getKey().toString(), entry.getValue().toString());
        }

        return html;
    }

       public static String bbcode2(String text) {
        String html = text;

        HashMap<String,String> bbMap = new HashMap<String , String>();



        bbMap.put("\\[quote\\](.+?)\\[/quote\\]", "$1");

        bbMap.put("\\[url\\](.+?)\\[/url\\]", "$1");

        for (Map.Entry entry: bbMap.entrySet()) {
            html = html.replaceAll(entry.getKey().toString(), entry.getValue().toString());
        }

        return html;
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to parse html?

Comment: no  , I use "$1" for extracting the original content within the tag

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more about what this program is supposed to do?

Comment: Please read the input and  desired out. I am going to parse the content with bbcode and extract all the contents embraced by bbcode for content management

Comment: So is your problem in `bbcode2()`?

Comment: Raju, this is difficult to do - using regex anyway. Its easy to get the content of all top level `[tag][/tag]`, or all the innermost tag contents. But to get each level, the only way I can see to do this is get all the top level matches, then keep running the regex against the matches until there are no more matches to return.

Comment: for input `[quote]aaaaa[/quote]bbbbb[quote]ccccc[/quote]` your regex will return `aaaaa[/quote]bbbbb[quote]ccccc`

Comment: @RajuGujarati, just added a link to some working code in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the general Java regex to match pairs of BB Code tags:

```
\\[([^\\]]+)\\](.+?)\\[/\\1\\]
```

This will grab top level matches e.g. in `[a][b] hi [/b] hello [/a][c] yo [/c]`, group 2 will match `[b] hi [\b] hello` and `yo`. ([Demonstrated here](http://regexr.com?37ert))

---

Any regex solution is in my opinion going to require you to use recursion (outside of the regex) to find all matches. You're going to have to find all top level matches (add them to some array), then recursively use the same regex on each of the matches (adding them all to the same result array) until eventually no matches more matches can be found.

In that example you can see you'd need to then run the regex again on `[b] hi [\b] hello` to return the content of the `[b] hi [/b]` which is `hi`.

For example, for an input of :

```
[A] outer [B] [C] last one left [/C] middle [/B] [/A]  [A] out [B] in [/B] [/A]
```

First you, run the regex against that string and look at the group 2 matches:

```
outer [B] [C] last one left [/C] middle [/B]
out [B] in [/B]
```

Add those to the result array, then you run the regex against those matches and get:

```
 [C] last one left [/C] middle
 in
```

Add those to the result array, and again run it against those matches and get:

```
 last one left
 [no matches]
```

And finally you'd run it against `last one left` and get no more matches, so you're done.

**Raju, if you're unfamiliar with recursion it would be very beneficial for you to stop reading at this point and attempt to solve the problem yourself - come back if you give up. That said...**

---

A Java solution to this problem is:

```
public static void getAllMatches(Pattern p, String in, List<String> out) {
  Matcher m = p.matcher(in);           // get matches in input
  while (m.find()) {                   // for each match
    out.add(m.group(2));               // add match to result array
    getAllMatches(p, m.group(2), out); // call function again with match as input
  }
}
```

[And here is a working example on ideone](http://ideone.com/Xy4swR)

**ideone output:**

```
[A]outer[B][C]last one left[/C]middle[/B][/A] [A]out[B]in[/B][/A]
-----------
- outer[B][C]last one left[/C]middle[/B]
- [C]last one left[/C]middle
- last one left
- out[B]in[/B]
- in

[quote]http://www.yourube.com?watch?v=asasdsadsa [url]aisa[/url] [/quote]
-----------
- http://www.yourube.com?watch?v=asasdsadsa [url]aisa[/url] 
- aisa
```

Comment: **Raju, I have added working code to my answer however if you're at all new to the concept of recursion I highly recommend you try to solve this yourself first! It's a useful thing to wrap your head around.**

Comment: It seems that using recursion can ease a lot of handling errors when it comes to recursive regex matching. So...If my message has some arbitrary strings ( not bbocde closing tags anyway) at the end , I have to construct the regex to split into two groups, one for strings embbed in the bbcode , one for arbitrary strings after the bbcode tags  ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, what is your end goal here? - add it to the question if it's long to explain, an example would be useful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your previous help.

Question Edited, OGHaza , I am now using (.)[^\]](.)(]) with the tools you have used http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?37ert for testing . Once it works successfully, the recursion rest can split the tokens and add into the output list.

Comment: Consider adding `([^\[]*)` to the start and end of your regex - this will capture the text before and after BBCode (the group numbers will shift up by 1 since you're adding a group at the start). [Like this](http://regexr.com?37fmb). Note that for most of your matches the text at the start will be blank - since it's already been captured at the end of the previous match.

Comment: Excellent! It seems for a long way for me to become a good programmer when we comes to constructing a method using recursion and regex altogether...

Answer (score 0):

Not neatest way, but a non reg-ex way...

```
int lastIndex = 0;
String startString = "[quote]";
String endString = "[/quote]";
int start;
int end;
while (lastIndex != -1) {
   start = string.indexOf(startString, lastIndex);
   lastIndex = start;
   if (lastIndex == -1) {
      break;
   }
   end   = string.indexOf(endString, lastIndex);
   lastIndex = end;
   if (lastIndex == -1) {
      break;
   }
   System.out.println(string.substring(
       start  + startString.length,
       end + 1));
}
```